# How to get started with basic Raspberry Pi electronics?

Tags: electronics

I have received a RPi 3 kit as a gift with tons of sensors, cables, resistors, etc.

I have managed to get the typical LED demo working by following literal instructions but I don't understand how to e.g. connect of the sensors.

How do I know which resistor to use, and to which GPIO pins to connect them?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. This question is pretty broad and thus likely a bad fit for Stackexchange. However I would like to recommend to check the [MagPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/issues/) for some inspiration and plenty of tutorials. Really worth a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the resistor you need to know some parameters regarding the LED.

Normally a red LED has a forward voltage of approx 2volt and a current of 20mA and the output from the Raspberry Pi is 3,3volt.

This means that 1,3volt (Raspberry voltage - LED voltage) and 20mA is the values for the resistors. then lets take 1,3v/0,02A = resistor (65ohm).

And what GPIO pin to use, well that's up to which pin you fancy in the programming.

Take a look at this video series, that will explain a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OR5h0UnMcUE

Table for LED,voltage vs. color

http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/images/7/7c/LED_FWV.jpg

Comment: There is also a some well written books, search for "electronics for makers"

Comment: Thank you, those are the figures I was looking for to get started.